Function.prototype.callを変数に入れて呼び出そうとするとエラーになるのはどうして？
一例ですが以下のように組み込みオブジェクトなどのメソッドを汎用的に使いたくて
Function.prototype.callの部分までを変数に入れて呼び出そうとするとエラーになります。
「not a function」と言われます。
typeofすると'function'って返ってくるのに「not a function」と言われます。
どうしてそうなりますか？
const hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
console.log(typeof hasOwnProperty) // 'function'
console.log(hasOwnProperty(['a'], 0)) // Uncaught TypeError: hasOwnProperty is not a function

// // ↓これはOK
// const hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
// hasOwnProperty.call(['a'], 0) // true

const toString = Object.prototype.toString.call
console.log(typeof toString) // 'function'
console.log(toString([])) // Uncaught TypeError: toString is not a function

// // ↓これはOK
// const toString = Object.prototype.toString
// toString.call([]) // '[object Array]'

const filter = Array.prototype.filter.call
console.log(typeof filter) // 'function'
console.log(filter(document.body.childNodes, node => node.nodeType === 1)) // Uncaught TypeError: filter is not a function

// // ↓これはOK
// const filter = Array.prototype.filter
// filter.call(document.body.childNodes, e => e.nodeType === 1) // Element[]

// 組み込み以外も同じ
const object = {
  prop: 'a',
  method(arg) {
    return this.prop + arg
  }
}
const method = object.method.call
console.log(typeof method) // 'function'
console.log(method({prop: 'b'}, '_arg')) // Uncaught TypeError: method is not a function

// // ↓これはOK
// const method = object.method
// method.call({prop: 'b'}, '_arg') // 'b_arg'

追記
callの部分をapplyやbindにしてみたら、applyやbindのエラーはもう少し詳しく書かれていました。
Firefoxはcallもapplyもbindも同じことが書かれたエラーでした。
Chromeのcallのばあいだけがあっさりしたエラーでした。

Chrome (129.0.6668.89)

call

Uncaught TypeError: hasOwnProperty is not a function


apply

Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function


bind

Uncaught TypeError: Bind must be called on a function




Firefox (131.0.3)

call

Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined


apply

Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply called on incompatible undefined


bind

Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.bind called on incompatible undefined





2件の回答後の追記
回答がむずかしくてわからないです…
エラーメッセージは違うけどメソッドを変数に入れる話と同じ話？…ですか？
メソッドを変数に入れる話↓
const object = {
  prop: 'a',
  method(arg) {
    return this.prop + arg
  }
}
const method = object.method
console.log(method('_arg'))

↑のばあいのエラーメッセージ↓

Chrome

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prop')


Firefox

Uncaught TypeError: this is undefined



.callまでを変数に入れたばあいとはエラーメッセージが違うのは

TypeErrorでどのようなメッセージを出すかは実装に任されています

ということ？…ですか？

chromeブラウザの検索でjavascript function.prototype.call 自身を変数に格納して呼び出すとすると、「AIによる概要」でそれらしき情報が出てきます。このメソッドは、呼び出すべき関数である this の値も読み取るため、保存して普通の関数として呼び出すことはできません。らしいですね。更にCopilotで根拠を尋ねると日本語になったページでは記述されていない Description - Function.prototype.call() の Warning の記述が根拠らしいです。私はその警告に書かれている内容がどう影響するのか意味が分からなかったのでご自身で調べてみてください。

@kunif
調べていただきありがとうございます。関数だけど関数じゃない…ってエラー内容がやさしくない…と思いました。

関数としては実行されています。しかし、関数内部の処理の途中で、thisが呼び出し可能ではない(IsCallable(this)がfalse)ため、TypeErrorを発生させています。TypeErrorでどのようなメッセージを出すかは実装に任されていますので、ブラウザーによっては差異が出ますが、TypeErrorになることは同じです。

より細かく見ていきましょう。JavaScriptの基底言語はECMAScriptになるため、ECMAScriptの仕様を確認する必要があります。Function.prototype.callの動作は仕様書に定められています。
https://tc39.es/ecma262/2024/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-function.prototype.call
この動作をJavaScriptで擬似的に書くと次のようになります。
Function.prototype.call = function(thisArg, ...args) {
  let func = this;
  if (isCallable(func) === false) throw new TypeError("ここは実装依存");
  PrepareForTailCall();
  return Call(func, thisArg, args);
}

上記のコードは本当のECMAScriptのコードではなく、内部処理を擬似的にあらわ利したモノです。ですので、コードにあるIsCallable、PrepareForTailCall、Callは実際のECMAScriptの関数ではなく、抽象操作(abstract operaiton)というもので、言語エンジン内部で関数のように使われる他から呼び出すことができる操作(operation)であり。ECMAScript上で直接使用することはできません。また、この処理が一つずつ行われるとは限らず、結果が同じであれば、実際の処理ではより最適化されている場合があります。
このようなFunction.prototype.callをレシーバーがない形で関数を呼び出した場合、thisは次のようになります。

bindや=>等で事前にthisが束縛されている場合は、束縛されたオブジェクトになる。
1.ではなく、with構文内で、withで指定したオブジェクトに呼び出すメソッドがある場合は、withで指定したオブジェクトになる。
1.でも2.でもない場合は、undefinedになる。ただし、非厳格モードでは、thisに対してundefinedをglobalThisに置き換えるため、globalThisになる。

ほとんどの場合は、3.のパターンであり、undefindもglobalThisも呼び出し可能ではないため、TypeErrorを発生します。

参考までに、bindにした場合や、with構文でメソッド呼び出しになる場合の例を出しておきます。
const f = function () {
  console.log(this.toString());
};
const fCall = f.call;
const fCallBind = fCall.bind(f);
f.fCall = fCall;
f.f = f;

f(); // [object global]
try { fCall("fCall"); } catch (e) { console.log(e.name); } // TypeError
fCall.call(f, "fCall.call") // fCall.call
fCallBind("fCallBind"); // fCallBind
with (f) {
  f(); // function () { ... }
  fCall("fCall with f"); // fCall with f
  call("call with f"); // call with f
}


教えていただいた内容はむずかしくてわからないけどとにかくエラーになるから考えるのはやめて避けて通ろうという方向に向かっています（たいへん申し訳ありません理解できる段階に達していません）

call自体がfunctionなのでそれを格納した変数もfunctionになります
function型に属するデータの種類には関数とラムダ式の二つがあります
関数は内部にthis引数を持ちます
これはクラスに紐づくものでなく、スコープに紐づきます
オブジェクト指向言語ではthisがオブジェクトインスタンスを指し示すため、同じように捉えがちですが、性質が異なるものなので注意しなければいけません
JSにおける関数は型の一種であり、いわばサンプルです
変数は関数のポインタとして機能するのではなく、そのサンプルの複製として振る舞います
つまりある関数を格納するとは、
その関数を基にした新たな関数を定義することに等しく、この時this引数が参照するスコープもその変数が宣言されたスコープに束縛されることになります
この仕様はメソッドでも同様です
この時内部のthisの参照先も変更されるため、グローバルスコープに束縛されるこの関数のthisから指定の関数もといメソッドが取得されない場合、すなはちグローバルスコープに指定のメンバメソッドが不在の場合はnot definedが返ります
関数定義時にはfunctionをキーワードとして指定します
例えばオブジェクトスコープの中で関数を作成すると、その関数ではthisがそのオブジェクトスコープに対する参照を持ちます
const object={
    message:"Success!",
    proc:function(){
        console.log(this.message)
    }
}

object.proc() //Success!

const sample={
    message:"OK!",
    test:object.proc
}

sample.test() //OK!

const run=object.proc
run() //undefined

class ProtoType{
    Test(){
        console.log(this)
    }
}

const type=new ProtoType()
type.Test() //ProtoType {}
const log=type.Test
log() //undefined

さて、件のコードではエラーがnot functionとなっています
このケースを想定する場合、ここではhasOwnPropertyというメンバがグローバルスコープに存在しないことになりますが、このエラーは主にラムダ式でオブジェクトスコープ内の関数を参照した場合に頻出のメッセージです
ラムダ式は関数と異なり値として扱われ、thisを持ちません
変数に対しても、複製ではなく参照が渡ります
例えば以下のようなコードでは同一のエラーを確認することができます
const sample={
    proc:function(){
        return "Success!"
    },
    test:function(){
        const func=this.proc
        console.log(func())
    }
}

sample.test() //Success!
const log=sample.test
console.log(log) //[Function: test]
log() //func is not a function

ここでのthisはいわゆるクロージャに閉包される外部変数であり、ラムダ式がクロージャとして機能します
このthisにとって、参照スコープとはオブジェクトスコープを持つ変数が宣言されるスコープです
すなはちcallを保持するhasOwnPropertyは、自身が宣言されるグローバルスコープ内でcallの内側のthis.memberを使用していることになります
内部ではこれがもう一つのhasOwnPropertyに格納され、関数として呼び出されようとしています
つまりエラーの原因はcallがクロージャであることに由来します

教えていただいた内容はむずかしくてわからないけどとにかくエラーになるから考えるのはやめて避けて通ろうという方向に向かっています（たいへん申し訳ありません理解できる段階に達していません）
